# Curvature From Calculus of Variations?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curvature

Consider the arclength functional
$$
S[y] = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} \ dx
$$
The functional derivative is given by
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta y} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} \right)
$$
with $L(y, y', x) = \sqrt{1 + (y')^2}$. We compute
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta y} &= 0  - \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 + (y')^2}}\right)
\\&= -\frac{\sqrt{1 + (y')^2} \ y'' - \frac{(y')^2 y''}{\sqrt{1 + (y')^2}}}{1 + (y')^2}
\\&= - \frac{(1 + (y')^2)y'' - (y')^2 y''}{(1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\\&= -\frac{y''}{(1 + (y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\\&= -k
\end{align}
where $k$ is the signed curvature of the graph of $y(x)$.  This makes sense: curvature is the local obstruction to a path being as short as possible.

What happens if we generalize to
$$
S[x^\mu] = \int_a^b \sqrt{\dot{x}^\mu g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\nu} \ d\lambda
$$
That is, what interpretation can we give to
$$
K_\mu \equiv \frac{\delta S}{\delta x^\mu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu} - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu} \right)
$$
with $L =  \sqrt{\dot{x}^\mu g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\nu}$?

Comment: the equations of a geodesic of a curve on a surface